# How to identify the ratio of oxidation states in terbium ions in its mixed oxide?

Tags: stoichiometry, oxidation-state

> Estimate the ratio of $\ce{Tb^3+}$ to $\ce{Tb^4+}$ in  $\ce{Tb_6O_11}$.

For my solution I knew that I had to get a sum of 22 positive charges from 6 $\ce{Tb^3+}$ and $\ce{Tb^4+}$ ions, so I just added different combinations until I found that $4(\ce{Tb^4+})+2(\ce{Tb^3+})$ gave me the desired value to have an overall neutral oxidation state on the molecule. This gives a $2:1$ ratio also. Is this the correct way to do this, or is there a more formal method?

Comment: your way looks good to me

Comment: Well, trying different combinations is definitely a lot better than just sit there and stare at it. You could go with a linear equation, but with numbers like these it is hardly any faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is certainly a formal way. Let $x$ and $y$ be the number of $\ce{Tb^3+}$ and $\ce{Tb^4+}$ ions respectively. Then:

$$\begin{align}
3x + 4y &= 22 \\
x + y &= 6
\end{align}$$

This is a simple system of two linear equations in two unknowns, and I am sure you know of many ways to solve it. Let's just solve it using matrices for the fun of it:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
22 \\
6
\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix} &= \frac{1}{3\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 4}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -4 \\
-1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
22 \\
6
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= -
\begin{pmatrix}
1\cdot 22 - 4\cdot 6 \\
-1 \cdot 22 + 3\cdot 6
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

as you found. It seems that trial and error may well be faster!